# Open Source and Proprietary Graphics Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

For some reason, I have a special need that I want to toggle between Nouveau Open Source and Nvidia Proprietary Graphics drivers very often. Normally, I go to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers to change the drivers, after that I need to restart ubuntu to make the change effective. That's too annoying.

I have a idea that as the graphics drivers are compile as the kernel module. So is there any way that I can generate to version of the kernel with two different driver, and select which kernel version I  want to boot in advance at the Grub loader. So that I don't need to change the graphics driver manually after I boot ubuntu OS.

Thank you very much.